# Locate multiple files with the same extension batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing this batch script but when it gets to looking fore if all files of a file extension exists, it goes and does the else even those the file exists.  Thanks for the help in advance!

```
@echo off
if not exist C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\workBackup (
    ::creates new folder 'workBackup'
    mkdir C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\workBackup
)

set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~10,4%

if not exist C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\workBackup\%TIMESTAMP% (
    ::creates new folder to put work into
    mkdir C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\workBackup\%TIMESTAMP%    
)

if not exist C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\workBackup\%TIMESTAMP%\logs (
    ::creates logs folder
    mkdir C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\workBackup\%TIMESTAMP%\logs
)

if exist C:\User\%USERNAME%\Documents\workspace\out\log\*.xlsx (
    ::moves all xlsx files to workBackup folder
    move "C:\User\%USERNAME%\Documents\workspace\out\log\"*.xlsx C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\workBackup\%TIMESTAMP%\
) else (
    ::exits if file no files are found
    echo "Files not found" 
    exit /b
)
if exist C:\User\%USERNAME%\Documents\workspace\out\log\*.xlsx (
    ::moves all log files to workBackup folder
    move "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\workspace\out\log\"*.log C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\workBackup\%TIMESTAMP%\logs
) else (
    ::exits if file no files are found
    echo "Files not found" 
    exit /b
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to mention

- the date format is a per user setting, better get date from wmic
- when creating a folder structure the deepest one will imply the other
- don't test, make and suppress an eventual error msg.
- reduce errorprone redundancy by creating vars
- put double quotes around the whole path not only part of it

---

```
@echo off
for /f %%A in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]') do Set _DT=%%A
Set yy=%_DT:~0,4%&Set MM=%_DT:~4,2%&Set dd=%_DT:~6,2%

Set "WBu=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\workBackup"
Set "WBuDT=%WBu%\%dd%%MM%%yy%"
:: or reverse day and month %MM%%dd%%yy%
Set "WSpOL=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\workspace\out\log"

mkdir "%WBuDT%\logs" 2>NUL

::moves all xlsx files to workBackup folder
move "%WSpOL%\*.xlsx" "%WBuDT%\" 2>NUL||(Echo "%WSpOL%\*.xlsx" not found&Exit /b)

::moves all log files to workBackup folder
move "%WSpOL%\*.log" "%WBuDT%\logs\" 2>NUL||(Echo "%WSpOL%\*.log" not found&Exit /b)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the feedback and help.  I'll be trying this out tomorrow when I have my system available!

Comment: Just tried it,  It still can't find the files.  I tried both types by commenting out the move command.  Any other ideas?

Comment: There was a typo (missing s in users) Otherwis I did a test here, created all the folders and the batch works as expected.